# JQuery for fixed position of navigation bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I am new to `JavaScript` please can anyone tell me the `JQuery` for keeping the navigation bar fixed on top while I scroll down.
I am using the following code but i think some contents are missing

**Code Snippet :**

```
var fixmeTop = $('.fixme').offset().top; 
$(window).scroll(function() { 
    var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop(); 
    if (currentScroll >= fixmeTop) { 
        $('.fixme').css({ position: 'fixed', top: '0', left: '0' }); 
    } 
    else { 
        $('.fixme').css({ position: 'static' }); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: Even though there is no code, this is more of an css issue than javascript.

Comment: your code is missing here, edit and update with the code. and most probably you can use `position:fixed;` in css to set your nav bar fixed.

Comment: @KilianStinson the code is in above comment

Comment: @Kevin B why did u do so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   var fixmeTop = $('.fixme').offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (currentScroll > fixmeTop) {
            $('.fixme').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0', left: '0'});
        } else {
            $('.fixme').css({position: 'static'});
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: it is showing => Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Comment: just **>** not => , its like **if( currentScroll >  fixmeTop)**, remove =

Comment: i dint get that one

Comment: Did you tried different browsers? Your code is working at my end, it was just condition that I thought is not matching your requirement. Still if it is not working please share HTML and CSS of same as well.

Comment: body { height: 3000px; }
.content { height: 300px; }
.fixme { background: green; color: white; text-align: center; width: 100%; height:30px; }

Comment: <html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="nav.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="fixme">Scroll here</div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: those are html and css files

Comment: Just updated the answer. In this case jquerry is not being loaded before DOM. You need to add $( document ).ready() function in order to load it after DOM

Comment: Thank u @boyz it worked

Answer (score -2):

If you want it fixed all the time, use something like:

```
.class_name {
    position: fixed;
}
```

If you want it fixed only when you scroll, but relative when you are at the top of the page, then use something like:

```
$('body').scroll(function(){

 var $class_name = $('.class_name');

 if($(this).scrollTop() >= $class_name.height()) {
  $class_name.addClass('scrolled');
 }
});
```

You can then use css to change the position based on the class on the element.

```
.class_name.scrolled {
    position: fixed;
}
```

If you couple this will `transition` css, you will be able to animate it smoothly.